# Query if array column contains one or more values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails 5 application, with a PostgreSQL 9.6 database.

The application has `Report` model, with a `department_ids` array field, which is defined in `schema.rb` as:

```
t.integer "department_ids", default: [], array: true
```

I need to write a query which returns report rows where the `department_ids` column contains one or more of a given set of department_ids.

My current workaround is to do this in Ruby with:

```
department_ids = [2, 5]

reports = Report.all.select do |report|
  (report.department_ids & department_ids).any?
end
```

However, using `select` has the downside of returning an `Array` instead of `ActiveRecord::Relation`, which means I need to hydrate the filtered results back into `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects.

```
Report.where(id: reports.map(&:id))
```

I'd like to avoid that step, and handle this all in a single query.

How can I write query like this with Active Record?

Comment: Why have you want with such field? Maybe you need to define report_id in department or make a association many to many?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Report.where('department_ids @> ARRAY[?]::integer[]', [2, 5])
```

You could find more information about array functions and operators [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-array.html)

Comment: For anyone wondering what "@>" means. It is the "contains" operator in PostgreSQL. It is defined for several data types - arrays, range types, geometric types, JSON(and JSONB).

Comment: As per other comment you might want to use `&&` for overlap.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my scope examples.

First one will search for at least one intersection (record column will contain at least one)
Second one will require to match all (!) of the items in the array

```
scope :tagged_one_of, -> (tags) { tags ? where("tags && ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", tags) : all }
scope :tagged_all_of, -> (tags) { tags ? where("tags @> ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", tags) : all }
```

Example:

```
Product.where(filter).where(sub_filter).tagged_one_of(tags_array)
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why they didn't include the `&&` syntax in the docs (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array)